# date_select show only specific days

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How could I show only mondays (for example) in days select?

```
= f.date_select :start_date, start_year: Date.current.year, end_year: Date.current.year + 1
```

I know how to do this with js, but is there a way to do this in pure Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a mondays method to your model:

```
def self.mondays(starts: nil, ends: nil)
  starts ||= Date.new(Date.current.year) 
  ends ||= Date.new(Date.current.year + 1)
  (starts..ends).select {|d| d.monday? }
end
```

Unfortunately `date_select` cannot be used with an arbitrary collection of dates, and using the data select format with 3 selects does not really work when you only have 4 days per month.

Instead you can use

```
= f.collection_select : start_date, MyModel.mondays, :iso_8601, :to_s
```

You could possible group into months with [grouped_collection_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html).